# is it safe to use [unowned self] in RxSwift Drivers?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

example:

```
tapGestureRecognizer.rx.event.asDriver()
    .drive(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

since the `disposeBag` is controlled by self, I would assume yes?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if disposeBag is an member variable of self, that is safe.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because when the object `self` points to would become dereferenced, that's the point in time where the object is deallocated, and thus its `disposeBag` property with it. When the `disposeBag` is deallocated, all of its disposables will be removed, which means all of its subscriptions are unsubscribed. So the lifetime of the `drive(onNext:)` subscription is tied to the lifetime of `self`. That means the closure will not be executed in a crashing case.

Comment: I think you can't be so sure about it. Depends on internal implementation and thread race. For example if http client captured your closure and invoked request, then even if `disposeBag` cancels subscription, there still might be a race-condition and http client may invoke your closure just after disposing self.